# Insert/Save CustomObject and account fields using visualforce page?

Tags: apex, visualforce

For external users, we will be sending a link in the email to fill survey and when they click submit.

1. A record should be created/saved into salesforce custom Object(Survey__c)
2. This Survey object has a lookup field which is Account, this should also be saved.

How do I achieve this?

Below is my code:

**VisualForce Page**

```
<apex:page controller="myAudit">
    <apex:form >
        <apex:pageblock >
            <apex:inputField  value="{!account.name}"/>
            <apex:inputText id="Survey" value="{!txtSurvey}"/>
              <apex:commandButton action="{!save}" value="save"/>
        </apex:pageblock>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

**Controller**

```
public class myAudit {

    public String account { get; set; }
    public String txtAuditQ { get; set; }
    public PageReference save() {
        //Add your custom logic to update specific fields here 
        Survey__c aq = new Survey__c();
        aq.Name = txtSurvey;
        aq.account__c = account;
        insert aq;
        return null;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SFSE! Please take a moment to visit the [help], scroll through the [tour], and read [ask]. What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck? Right now it does not appear that you have made a good faith effort to research or solve this problem before posting here.

Comment: Please **[edit]** your post to be more clear about why what you have so far does not meet your needs.

Comment: I'm able to save the custom object but not able to populate the account lookup in the customobject

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your code `aq.account__c = account;` You are assigning Account which is string to the lookup field. Thats why it is not giving you AccountId after saving.

> Small changes are suggested.

Declare Account as object instead of String

```
public Account accountObj { get; set; }
```

In the visualforce, for `<apex:inputField>` use `Account.Id`,  which will give you Account Lookup.

```
<apex:inputField  value="{!accountObj.Id}"/>
```

In the Controller make this change `aq.account__c = accountObj.Id;`

**Controller**

```
public class myAudit {

    public Account accountObj { get; set; }
    public String txtAuditQ { get; set; }

    public PageReference save() {
        //Add your custom logic to update specific fields here 
        Survey__c aq = new Survey__c();
        aq.Name = txtSurvey;
        aq.account__c = accountObj.Id;
        insert aq;
        return null;
    }
  }
}
```

Finally, since you are performing DML so use try-catch block as a matter of best practices.